# SQL Server XML modify remove nodes without attributes or inner text

Tags: sql-server, xpath

I need to be able to delete all nodes with any name as long as **(a) the node has no attributes** *or* **(b) the node has no inner text.**

Sample XML:

`<mydoc>
  <delete_me />
  <keep_me value="yes!" />
  <but_do_not_keep_me></but_do_not_keep_me>
  <should_you_keep_me>Absolutely!</should_you_keep_me>
</mydoc>`

The expected output is

`<mydoc>
  <keep_me value="yes!" />
  <should_you_keep_me>Absolutely!</should_you_keep_me>
</mydoc>`

I've got the queries figured out to satisfy one condition or the other.

`@xml.modify('delete //*[empty(@*)]')`

This will only keep elements with an attribute. Similarly,

`@xml.modify('delete //*[empty(node())]')`

will remove all empty nodes. But I cannot figure out how to accomplish both. If I try to do a union `|`, that gives me the error `XQuery [modify()]: The XQuery syntax 'union' is not supported.`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So `'delete //*[empty(node()) and empty(@*)]'` ?

Comment: @ZLK You are a genius. I've been using the `|` for "and". I had no idea you could use the actual text `and` to accomplish the same thing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @ZLK's comment above, the `and` keyword is allowed.

`@xml.modify('delete //*[empty(node()) and empty(@*)]')`

works perfectly.